# increment each number in list by 1 using linq

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

is it possible to add 1 to each number in a list of integer using linq

this is what i have tried:

```
m.Pages = insertedPageList.ForEach(Function(x As Integer) x+= 1)
```

but this inst working. 
the only way i can make it work is to do this:

```
For x As Integer = 0 to insertedPageList.Count - 1 
    insertedPageList(x) = insertedPageList(x) + 1
Next

m.Pages = insertedPageList
```

is there a way of making this work with linq?
i tried searching the forms and google but cant find an answer to this specific question.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in LINQ? Do you understand why your example isn't working?

Comment: Are you trying to make a copy of the original collection? If so, then the answer with Select() is probably just right. Otherwise, the foreach loop you have should be correct.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try:

```
m.Pages = insertedPageList.Select(Function(x As Integer) x + 1).ToList()
```

But it will create a new list and overwrite the old one... so it's not really efficient.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but how does the select replace the For each loop?

Comment: Select() returns a new IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: @user1753377 The `Select` will let you formulate a "selection method" for each element. In this example the `Select` "Selects" each element + 1. Btw; thanks is expressed by upvoting :-)

Comment: One note regarding to the use of `ForEach`, since the `Integers` are structs i.e. value types, altering their value wouldn't guarantee altering their value in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `For Each` loop with LINQ, but there are no advantages except vertical line space:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, m.Pages.Count).ToList().ForEach(Sub(i As Integer) m.Pages(i) += 1)
```